# i3 /usr/bin/dunst draining memory

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, ram

I have a problem with dunst - "Lightweight" notification-deamon.

A couple times a day it seems to drain all of my ram, like 98%. I have to manually kill it each time and it annoys me. I have not found a good answer for why this happens or how prevent it, i am using i3 as window manager. I appreciate all answers that can help me. My specifications can be seen below:

[image]

Specs:

```
MSI GT780R-223NE (Laptop)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz × 8
Ram: 7,8 GiB
Disk 729.8 GB
Graphics: NVIDIA GTX 560m
```

Edit:
It seems that the Memory usage increases with time, it is not a sudden change. Using it with spotify, and each time i change song the reserved memory usage increases by ~80MB.

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO, but it appears there is a memory leak in the program. You can see on dunst's issue tracker that someone else has already [reported one](https://github.com/knopwob/dunst/issues/251).

Comment: It is so interesting I'm using dunst with these conf https://gist.github.com/81ff370c94483858778c spotify and chromium sometimes leaks and I stop each time. But I didn't see any dunst leaks, You may compare the conf there may be a conf issue.

Comment: I'm on debian Wheezy btw, it may also be a ubuntu related problem.

Comment: Yes i realize this is off-topic I apologize for that.

Tried your config FZE, same problem occurs, yeah it might be an ubuntu issue as well. Thanks for response though.

Comment: Ask your question at "AskUbuntu"

Answer (score 2):

This problem was discussed in [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dunst/+bug/1330480) and the solution seems to be to install alternative package for `dunst`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cpick/dunst
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: This is the right answer. As the repo itself will tell you when adding it, this is only required on Trusty Thar. Later versions of ubuntu have fixed versions available in their repos.